# is it possible to use jbuilder and active_model_serializers on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers, jbuilder

I use `active_model_serializers` on rails application. But for a resource (https://github.com/Textalk/angular-schema-form), I need to have more freedom on json structure. So I try to use jbuilder only for this resource but when I add jbuilder to my Gemfile, `active_model_serializers` is not more used in all previous resources.

So is it possible to have both at the same time ?